# Relevance of the deduction of similar theorems than Maier's theorem for other constellations of primes

Tags: limits, prime-numbers, soft-question, analytic-number-theory, limsup-and-liminf

Wikipedia has the article [Maier's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maier%27s_theorem). I would like to ask as a soft question about the importance of the deduction of similar statements for (different) arithmetic functions counting the number of primes $p\leq x$ in different constellations of primes (see the linked article). I know prime constellations as the primes in arithmetic progressions and different examples as the subsequences of prime numbers explained in pages 58-59 from the book [1], that is the Exercise 1.35.

> **Question.** I would like to know if you can to glimpse what about the importance of study similar statements or variants of Maier's theorem for different sequences of prime numbers (constellations of prime numbers with infinitely many terms). Can tell us these variants of Maier's theorem any important thing about the distribution of prime numbers? **Many thanks.**

Previous Wikipedia's article also refers the issue about the original Maier's theorem and Cramér random model for prime numbers.

I hope that it is clear what I'm asking as a soft question, this is about what is the importance/relevance of the attempting to prove new variants of Maier's theorem for constellations of primes (with a special importance in your opinion): if it is potentially interesting in the context of the study of the distribution of prime numbers (maybe, in the context of the open problems related to the distribution of prime numbers).

### References:

[1] Richard Crandrall and Carl Pomerance, *Prime Numbers: A Computational Perspective*, Second Edition, Springer (2005).

Comment: Many thanks for the person who upvoted the post.

Comment: I'm editing the same post on MathOverflow with identifier **428702** and same title.